# Jest : cannot find module

Tags: vue.js, jestjs

I generated an application with vue-cli and chose Jest as a test runner.
Everything works fine with the HelloWorld default vue.
I added to that ".vue" the following statement :

```
import aService from 'my-lib';
```

It works fine when I run the project with : `npm run dev`

However, when I run the test with `npm run test:unit`, I get the **`Cannot find module 'my-lib' from 'HelloWorld.vue'`** error :

```
> vue-cli-service test:unit

 FAIL  tests/unit/example.spec.js
  ● Test suite failed to run

    Cannot find module 'my-lib' from 'HelloWorld.vue'

      93 | 
      94 | <script>
    > 95 | import aService from 'my-lib';
         | ^
      96 | 
      97 | export default {
      98 |   name: 'HelloWorld',
```

**Why Jest cannot find my module ?** knowing that It runs well and that It's an ES6 module.

What I've tried so far : I added the following code to my `jest.config.js` file but didn't help:

```
module.exports = {
  preset: '@vue/cli-plugin-unit-jest',
  transformIgnorePatterns: [
    "node_modules/(?!(my-lib)/)"
  ],
  moduleDirectories: [
    "node_modules" 
  ],
};
```